# Does Maximum Likelihood Estimation Require the Data to be "Scaled"?

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, estimators

**Does Maximum Likelihood Estimation Require the Data to be "Scaled"?**

For instance, suppose I have the following data in R:

```
x <- c(3631, 1681, 188, 1065, 733, 643, 2001, 714, 180, 5147, 2541, 
1048, 643, 1356, 270, 4396, 358, 4025, 2004, 1879, 2342, 4138, 
616, 3161, 4904, 4320, 215, 79, 5431, 6551, 97, 889, 6009, 992, 
1487, 336, 840, 612, 769, 680, 5840, 603, 2581, 4087, 2241, 129, 
2366, 3856, 980, 1315, 1050, 7002, 36, 511, 529, 534, 3037, 1123, 
3889, 4611, 2577, 3953, 517, 774, 923, 295, 3152, 524, 714, 5135, 
2529, 1561, 6105, 4305, 3633, 1164, 1663, 791, 11, 225, 940, 
172, 4936, 348, 3410, 3205, 6827, 3846, 1809, 6580, 61, 892, 
4525, 523, 595, 3594, 2245, 999, 343, 856, 106, 1513, 224, 324, 
6725, 323, 2221, 6455, 3955, 3580, 532, 775, 3022, 3049, 1086, 
613, 2866, 4799, 158, 869, 2510, 149, 1809, 2772, 5474, 1096, 
5668, 381, 2428, 428, 308, 932, 1868, 490, 10163, 12, 671, 1676, 
536, 1940, 686, 1590, 5749, 1257, 1389, 3209, 562, 2504, 129, 
1617, 4058, 521, 2541, 57, 10747, 1795, 566, 3290, 372, 5624, 
1229, 252, 257, 1971, 707, 8036, 2934, 466, 378, 675, 1551, 2320, 
248, 2871, 4747, 2987, 6555, 369, 378, 443, 397, 7653, 1471, 
174, 764, 585, 291, 703, 440, 1808, 83, 3346, 2384, 2693, 52, 
678, 1320, 7359, 5367, 1527, 5789, 300, 101, 1749, 4265, 4095, 
2134, 326, 326, 1266, 424, 379, 2275, 206, 1740, 1593, 1448, 
7488, 1862, 4304, 436, 2609, 929, 1583, 325, 5153, 371, 572, 
884, 422, 10905, 2406, 1873, 4371, 75, 150, 1538, 1617, 7756, 
630, 691, 200, 1000, 964, 693, 444, 59, 2059, 1130, 1276, 1847, 
367, 1533, 875, 2434, 495, 2087, 1777, 3709, 335, 156, 280, 2528, 
2401, 1978, 511, 4999, 2568, 1398, 2637, 1668, 2077, 2993, 69, 
3699, 1667, 2584, 1915, 679, 4078, 3014, 555, 2690, 69, 930, 
1026, 324, 991, 973, 566, 459, 2338, 509, 785, 467, 355, 3186, 
5202, 1122, 5077, 4945, 1973, 3029, 377, 4871, 5481, 284, 801, 
444, 1196, 661, 25, 318, 1137, 1317, 2841, 143, 1139, 1662, 1012, 
88, 1764, 1203, 3618, 713, 8657, 1274, 2255, 96, 784, 1687, 62, 
1211, 952, 125, 3260, 879, 430, 3096, 499, 699, 2395, 1704, 5818, 
2754, 2012, 6724, 2891, 959, 1730, 962, 182, 210, 6051, 902, 
3759, 2211, 206, 1408, 1472, 883, 773, 2479, 529, 2932, 1421, 
2111, 1829, 847, 2761, 1060, 1805, 1348, 2049, 2507, 809, 502, 
5877, 1621, 2254, 1329, 2752, 1657, 167, 526, 616, 198, 1648, 
1329, 1643, 360, 1028, 923, 2819, 1856, 4562, 2547, 2517, 6200, 
1704, 10, 1838, 333, 1643, 1561, 985, 2763, 4939, 3116, 855, 
1405, 891, 4503, 210, 4406, 4836, 33, 97, 4957, 2202, 1709, 6048, 
123, 1193, 13006, 271, 781, 2005, 2970, 352, 1600, 1862, 2945, 
5234, 502, 2943, 1666, 167, 4473, 468, 795, 3175, 1114, 6, 579, 
42, 995, 2705, 1929, 594, 809, 572, 871, 470, 802, 773, 7028, 
430, 139, 215, 1328, 117, 1324, 1451, 1455, 157, 1347, 1049, 
2391, 301, 1587, 602, 1197, 199, 4400, 1883, 1971, 1849, 8050, 
7730, 2527, 4066, 4443, 54, 838, 16, 584, 261, 579, 729, 226, 
292, 1367, 1608, 749, 1351, 3710, 2219, 369, 628)
```

I tried to fit different probability distributions to these observations:

```
library(fitdistrplus)

fg  <- fitdist(x, "gamma")
fln <- fitdist(x, "lnorm")
fg  <- fitdist(x, "gamma")
fw  <- fitdist(x, "weibull")
```

But these all returned the following errors:

```
<simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     gr = gradient, ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth,     lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): non-finite finite-difference value [2]>
Error in fitdist(d$df, "gamma") : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 100
```

However, when the data is "scaled" - the above code seems to work fine:

```
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)

xx <- x/20000
fg <- fitdist(xx, "gamma")
fln <- fitdist(xx, "lnorm")
fw <- fitdist(xx, "weibull")
L <- list(fg, fln, fw)

a <- denscomp(L, plotstyle = "ggplot")
b <- qqcomp(L, plotstyle = "ggplot")
c <- cdfcomp(L, plotstyle = "ggplot")
d <- ppcomp(L, plotstyle = "ggplot")

a+b+c+d
```

[image]

**My Question:** Does anyone know why this is? In general, does MLE require the data to be "scaled"?

**References:**

- https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v064i04

Comment: What you are doing is unclear, because the statements that you claim produce errors do not appear to have anything to do with the data you initially show.  You can find thousands of applications and explanations of MLE on this site and just about any one of them will show you scaling is unnecessary.  In many cases it would be counterproductive and produce incorrect results.

Comment: @ whuber: thank you for your reply! I have fixed the statements in question

Comment: Forgive me for sounding sceptical, but the error message does not match the code that precedes it.

Comment: @ Whuber: thank you for your reply! This is the error I get: <simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     gr = gradient, ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth,     lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): non-finite finite-difference value [2]>
Error in fitdist(x, "gamma") : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 100

Comment: What does the documentation for that software say about error code 100?

Comment: @ Whuber: thank you for your reply! I was able to find this link that provides some information about "error code 100": https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/vignettes/FAQ.html#the-optimization-algorithm-stops-with-error-code-100.-what-shall-i-do

Comment: I tried the following change as suggested by the link (but I still got an error): fg <- fitdist(x, "gamma" , control=list(trace=1, REPORT=1))

Comment: I will keep looking, maybe there might be a way to fix this problem

Comment: The software tells you to do three things, in order.  In order to answer your question we need to know the specific outcomes of those actions.